# How to check if file exists but generalized in the middle of a path in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

So I want to check if file exists but in this way

```
if [ -e "out/head/tnt-*/output.log" ]
then
    echo "FILE IS THERE"

else
    echo "NOT THERE"
fi
```

Even though the file is present it will go to else condition unless I change the

```
tnt-* to tnt-14
```

I want to keep it tnt-* because for some automation runs it could tnt-13, tnt-10 or tnt-14.

Can some one suggest another way of checking for a file here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes to enable the shell expansion:

```
if [ -e out/head/tnt-*/output.log ]
then
  echo "FILE IS THERE"
else
  echo "NOT THERE"
fi
```